# Symfony 3.x DocumentManager SymfonyCMF PHPCR-ODM

Tags: symfony, symfony3

Работаю с **Symfony CMF**, пытаюсь получить данные класса **Page** из **DocumentManager**, в документации по **Doctrine** есть пример получения данных через **DocumentManager** идентичный моего кода, но почему то возвращается пустой массив, путь до класса верный, проверял. Смотрю в логи **Symfony**, интересный момент, в **doctrine.DEBUG** выводятся все элементы, которые нужны, но только одно поле - **url**, но там точно есть как минимум **title** и **node_name**, в чем пробелма? почему в перменной **$page** пустой массив а в логи выводит все данные? и как получить хотя бы их..?

```
/**
 * @Route("/getSupportMenu")
 */
public function getSupportMenuAction (Request $request) {
    $output = [
        'output' => [],
        '$request' => $request,
    ];
    $locale = $request->getLocale ();

    $this->dm->getLocaleChooserStrategy ()->setLocale ($locale);

    $qb = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder ();
    $qb
        ->from ()
            ->document ('ПутьДоСущности:Page', 'p')
        ->end ();
    $pages = $qb->getQuery ()->getResult ();
    $output['$pages'] = $pages;

    return new JsonResponse ($output);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был прост:
В переменной **$page** хранился **ArrayCollection**, необходимо получить данные из этого класса примерно таким способом:

```
$pages = $qb->getQuery ()->getResult ()->toArray ();
```

В таком случае в **$page** будет возвращен массив с данными, а не путь до класса **ArrayCollection**.